# Image not getting centered

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my logo centered in the middle of the page but it is always to the right of the center line. I am new to CSS and have been googling for the solution for over an hour now with no luck here is my code:

```
#Container{
    width: 100%;
}

#logo{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#col{
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>tesing/title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <LINK href="CLL1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/Logo.jpg"/></div>
        <div id="Container">


        <div id="col">              
            <select name="thing">
                <option value=0>Category
             </select>

             <select name="model">
                 <option>Sub Category</option>
              </select>

             <select name="color">
                 <option>Sub Sub Category</option>
               </select>            
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YTXwQ/

Comment: @j08691 ... you just taught me about the wonder of placekitten.com. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Also, try putting your logo in the container and see what happens.

Comment: @Yamaha are you looking horizental center or what........

Comment: it looks like you have forgotton to close the `<title>` tag correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is probably wider than `200px`.  If so, it'll overflow beyond the right side of the `#logo` div, and the centering will appear to be "off toward the right".  You can see an example of this situation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/vPx2H/)

To constrain the image to the width of the `#logo` div, just add this css:

```
#logo img { max-width: 100%; }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/vPx2H/1/) is the example, updated to include the image constraint above.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS will center the `#logo` div just fine. If it looks off still, make sure the logo is centered in the actual 200px wide image of yours.

Alternative approach to center (using absolute positioning):

```
#logo {
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px; /* negative half of total width */              
}
```

This is just another method to center if you need absolute positioning. Otherwise your `margin:0 auto` will work. But make sure too your logo is center in your logo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

try this `#logo{ text-align:center;}`

Comment: answer should be more descriptive